# Why use "con que" instead of just "que"?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, selección-de-palabras

In the below sentence, why use "con que" instead of just "que"?

> Un funcionario del banco central se encontró con que el dispositivo conectado a los sistemas de mensajería financiera Swift no funcionaba.
>
> A central bank official found that the device connected to Swift financial messaging systems did not work.
>
> [(translated by google translate)](https://translate.google.com/#view=home&op=translate&sl=es&tl=en&text=Un%20funcionario%20del%20banco%20central%20se%20encontr%C3%B3%20con%20que%20el%20dispositivo%20conectado%20a%20los%20sistemas%20de%20mensajer%C3%ADa%20financiera%20Swift%20no%20funcionaba)
>
> [the sentence is from this article](https://elpais.com/economia/2016/03/17/actualidad/1458200294_374693.html)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to the *Diccionario panhispánico de dudas*, the verb *[encontrar](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/?key=encontrar)*, used with the meaning of "finding someone or something unexpectedly or by chance", can be used in two ways:

- As the usual transitive verb:

  > Alguien llamó a la puerta. Abrió y encontró a Ángela.
- Or most frequently, as an intransitive, pronominal verb followed by the *con* preposition:

  > Alguien llamó a la puerta. Abrió y **se** encontró **con** Ángela.

So as you may now see, the verb in your example is used in this second way:

> Un funcionario **se** encontró **con** que el dispositivo no funcionaba.

If used in the first way, the sentence would be like this (and also valid):

> Un funcionario encontró que el dispositivo no funcionaba.